# Tricky MySQL query with joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 4 tables (among a lot of others - just showing the relevant ones). They are:

- "users"

  - id
  - name
  - role_id
- "roles"

  - id
  - name
- "chapter_role_view_permissions"

  - id
  - chapter_id
  - role_id
- "chapters"

  - id
  - name

I'm trying to build a query that will return to me a list of all users, their role name, all chapters per user, and whether or not they have view access to each chapter. So lets say there are 2 users and 2 chapter. User 1 is role_id=1 and User 2 is role_id=2. And the chapter_role_view_permissions has 1 record ( id:1 | chapter_id: 1 | role_id: 1 ) which means only users with role_id=1 can view chapter 1.

The query result I am looking for should be something like:

|---users.id---|--roles.id---|---chapters.id--|-can_view_chapter-|

|------ 1 ------|----- 1 -------|------- 1 --------|----------- 1 -----------|

|------ 1 ------|----- 1 -------|------- 2 --------|----------- 0 -----------|

|------ 2 ------|----- 2 -------|------- 1 --------|----------- 0 -----------|

|------ 2 ------|----- 2 -------|------- 2 --------|----------- 0 -----------|

Any idea what the query might look like? I don't want to have to make a new field in chapter_role_view_permissions that says "allowed" and insert new records for each role type with either allowed=1 or allowed=0

Comment: As a bonus, I have an additional table I have to join to the results of that called "quiz_user_statuses" which will join on the chapters.id field and users.id field that says what that user scored on that particular chapter (and have NULL if the record doesn't exist AKA they haven't taken the chapter quiz yet or they don't have the permission to take the quiz).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT users.name, roles.name, chapters.name
FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN chapter_role_view_permissions link ON link.role_id = roles.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN chapters ON chapters.id = link.chapter_id
```

Comment: This is close. The only problem is in this case, it would only return: |------ 1 ------|----- 1 -------|------- 1 --------|----------- 1 -----------| and not the 3 records where "can_view_chapter" (not a field in the DB, was hoping to create this field in the query) would = 0. And to clear it up even more, I was hoping can_view_chapter would be boolean. So even though users of role.id=2 can't view chapter 1 or chapter 2 (because a record doesn't exist in chapter_role_view_permissions that says chapter_id=1 and role_id=2) a record in the full query would appear with can_view_chapter=0

Comment: Pretty much their needs to be a record for each chapter per user. So if there are 5 users and 5 chapters, regardless of number of records in chapter_role_view_permissions, there needs to be 25 records returned ( 5 chapters x 5 users ). Each one needs to tell me the user id, the chapter id, and whether or not the user has permissions to view that chapter.

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> I'm trying to build a query that will return to me a list of **all
>   users**, **their role name**, **all chapters per user**, and whether or not they
>   have view access to each chapter

Just *translate* your own words in a query, in the same order:

```
SELECT users.id, roles.name, chapters.name FROM users
INNER JOIN roles ON  users.role_id=roles.id
INNER JOIN chapters ON users.id=chapters.id
WHERE users.id=USER_ID
```

Anyway, you have to explain better: how are you relating chapters and users? I assumed chapters.id is the same as user.id

Comment: It's a many to many situation with chapters and permissions. SO basically users are assigned a role. And chapter permissions are assigned to the users via their role (via the chapter_role_view_permissions table). Not sure if that helps clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    u.id, r.id, c.id, IFNULL(c.id, 0) AS can_view_chapter
FROM      users AS u
JOIN      roles AS r ON r.id = u.role_id
LEFT JOIN chapter_role_view_permissions AS p ON p.role_id = r.id
JOIN      chapters As c ON c.id = p.chapter_id
```